# messaging for command line programs

Tags: python

I tend to write a lot of command line utility programs and was wondering if 
there is a standard way of messaging the user in Python.  Specifically, I would like to print error and warning messages, as well as other more conversational output in a manner that is consistent with Unix conventions.  I could produce these myself using the built-in print function, but the messages have a uniform structure so it seems like it would be useful to have a package to handle this for me.

For example, for commands that you run directly in the command line you might 
get messages like this:

```
This is normal output.
error: no files given.
error: parse.c: no such file or directory.
error: parse.c:7:16: syntax error.
warning: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson:
    not found, skipping.
```

If the commands might be run in a script or pipeline, they should include their name:

```
grep: /usr/dict/words: no such file or directory.
```

It would be nice if could handle levels of verbosity.

These things are all relatively simple in concept, but can result in a lot of 
extra conditionals and complexity for each print statement.

I have looked at the logging facility in Python, but it seems overly complicated and more suited for daemons than command line utilities.

Comment: import logging; logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'). Sorry I didn't read your last line, up to then it was exactly what you were describing, sure it's good for daemons but command line app's equally.

Comment: The thing about using `logging` is that most of the libraries I import use it so it's worth using just to get debugging output from those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend [Inform](https://inform.readthedocs.io). It is the only package I have seen that seems to address this need. It provides a variety of print functions that print in different circumstances or with different headers. For example:

```
log()       -- prints to log file, no header
comment()   -- prints if verbose, no header
display()   -- prints if not quiet, no header
output()    -- always prints, no header
warning()   -- always prints with warning header
error()     -- always prints with error header
fatal()     -- always prints with error header, terminates program.
```

Inform refers to these functions as 'informants'. Informants are very similar to the Python print function in that they take any number of arguments and builds the message by joining them together. It also allows you to specify a *culprit*, which is added to the front of the message.

For example, here is a simple search and replace program written using Inform.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Replace a string in one or more files.

Usage:
    replace [options] <target> <replacement> <file>...

Options:
    -v, --verbose            indicate whether file is changed
"""

from docopt import docopt
from inform import Inform, comment, error, os_error
from pathlib import Path

# read command line
cmdline = docopt(__doc__)
target = cmdline['<target>']
replacement = cmdline['<replacement>']
filenames = cmdline['<file>']
Inform(verbose=cmdline['--verbose'], prog_name=True)

for filename in filenames:
    try:
        filepath = Path(filename)
        orig = filepath.read_text()
        new = orig.replace(target, replacement)
        comment('updated' if orig != new else 'unchanged', culprit=filename)
        filepath.write_text(new)
    except OSError as e:
        error(os_error(e))
```

Inform() is used to specify your preferences; comment() and error() are the
informants, they actually print the messages; and os_error() is a useful utility that converts OSError exceptions into a string that can be used as an error message.

If you were to run this, you might get the following output:

```
> replace -v tiger toe eeny meeny miny moe
eeny: updated
meeny: unchanged
replace error: miny: no such file or directory.
replace error: moe: no such file or directory.
```

Hopefully this gives you an idea of what Inform does. There is a lot more power there. For example, it provides a collection of utilities that are useful when printing messages. An example is os_error(), but there are others.  You can also define your own informants, which is a way of handling multiple levels of verbosity.

Comment: I decided to give Inform a try and I am very happy. It is very easy to use, produces clean output, and seems to be very flexible. It even supports logging. It seems to be a much better fit to the needs of command line programs than the logging package. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
```

`level` specified above controls the verbosity of the output.

You can attach handlers (this is where the complexity outweighs the benefit in my case) to the logging to send output to different places (https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#multiple-handlers-and-formatters) but I haven't needed more than command line output to date.

To produce output you must specify it's *verbosity* as you log it:

`logging.debug("This debug message will rarely appeal to end users")`

I hadn't read your very last line, the answer seemed obvious by then and I wouldn't have imagined that single `basicConfig` line could be described as "overly complicated". It's all I use the 60% of the time when print is not enough.